# How can select the tag name with the postion of mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**I can get selected the html tag with the position of mouse ?**

when i move with the mouse i can update for exmpel the border of tag in the position of mose .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mouseover` event on `document` and then can get tag name as below:

```
$(document).mouseover(function(e){
     let tagName = e.target.nodeName;
     //you can also get class in this as below
     let tagClass = e.target.className;    
});
```

Then you can add `css` on `class`/`id` or `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and get the `event.target`.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => console.log(event.target), false);
```